# What is %*d in c?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I have come across a code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n=5;
    printf("\nn=%*d",n,n);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs : `n= 5`. I know that `%*d` allows two parameters and returns the field width. However, I tried changing `n`'s value to `9`. But the output came in the same format (i.e. `n= 9`). Also , I am not 100% sure that I understand `%*d` and field width correctly.

Hence my question, what is `%*d` and field width in C.

Thanks.

### EDIT:

Ok, thanks everybody. I now have understood that it was my compiler which was combining spaces into one.

Comment: look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Using 9 gives more space.

Comment: @self. I use http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php and the output I get with code `    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int n=9;
        printf("\nn=%*d",n,n);
        return 0;
    }` is `n= 9` .

Answer (score 2):

It prints n having length n

```
printf("\nn=%*d",n,n);
```

The star stands for:

> The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional
>   integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be
>   formatted.

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: well * in format string, specifies to have minimum field width...say if i give n=6541 and field=4, then using printf("%*d",field,n)...will print 6541 without any extra spaces. but in your case taking n=9, which takes 1 space, so remaining 8 spaces will be added.

Answer (score 2):

If you read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you will see

> integer value or * that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with space characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. In the case when * is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the - flag specified and positive field width.

So the asterisk tells `printf` to get the field width from an argument. Since `n` is `5` in your example, the output will be four spaces and the number `5`, for a total of five characters in width.

If you do this in an online compiler then remember that web-browsers will not display all spaces in a text, unless in e.g. a `<pre>` block or if they are non-breaking spaces (like `&nbsp;`).

I suggest you do this in a text-console at your own computer, or try another online compiler that formats the output properly.

Answer (score 1):

Using 9:

```
n=        9Press any key to continue...
```

Using 5:

```
n=    5Press any key to continue...
```

That online compiler combines all spaces into one apparently.

Using a better one:

5: http://ideone.com/WMrki5

9: http://ideone.com/E1lGj7

Comment: Ok, I used a different compiler and got the result you are saying. Thanks. BTW, have you swapped the o/p for 5 and 9 in this answer?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yeah :), I'm multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers as well as your understanding is correct. It does adjusts the field width.

I will try to answer here why you are not seeing it in [online compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) you are using.

It actually does print 9 or 5 spaces as per your code. however, it's HTML, which compresses multiple spaces to single white space. If you want to see the exact output, check the HTML source of the output panel page.